# ConvexHullMesh fails for collinear points

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry

I've got a List of PointLists, of which some contain only collinear points.

I now want to obtain all `ConvexHullMesh`es of my PointLists.

For more than two collinear points, the algorithm seems to fail:

```
ConvexHullMesh[{{1, 0}, {0, 0}, {-1, 0}}]
```

while

```
ConvexHullMesh[{{1, 0}, {-1, 0}}]
```

would work.

How can I have `ConvexHullMesh` give me the correct ConvexHull for those cases (i.e. a line: `{{1,0},{-1,0}}`)?

Comment: So then, couldn't you use the failure of the convex hull algorithms as a test of collinearity?